# How to create a grouped product with the api in one post?

Tags: magento2, api

How can I create a grouped product with the magento api in only one post. I know I can create configurable products in only one post adding the options in the next attributes

```
"configurable_product_options": [
                {
                    "attribute_id": "663",
                    "label": "co_color_filtro",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "value_index": 9
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "configurable_product_links": []
```

How can I do this with a grouped product? Because the magento tutorial uses differents endpoint for create the product and add the simple items https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/tutorials/grouped-product/

I tried doing something like this

```
  "products": [
    {
      "sku": "new-grouped",
      "name": "New Grouped Product",
      "attribute_set_id": 4,
      "type_id": "grouped",
      "visibility": 4,
      "status": 0,
      "extension_attributes": {
        "website_ids": [4],
        "category_links": [
          {
            "position": 0,
            "category_id": "2083"
          }
        ],
        "product_links": [
          {
            "link_type": "associated",
            "linked_product_sku": "009-9031191",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 1,
            "extension_attributes": {
              "qty": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "link_type": "associated",
            "linked_product_sku": "009-9031220",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 2,
            "extension_attributes": {
              "qty": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "link_type": "associated",
            "linked_product_sku": "009-9036452",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 3,
            "extension_attributes": {
              "qty": 1
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use with endpoint POST rest/V1/products:

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "Luma-Group",
    "name": "Luma Group Of Bags",
    "attribute_set_id": 15,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "grouped",
    "extension_attributes": {
        "category_links": [
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "4"
            }
        ],
        "stock_item": {
            "is_in_stock": true
        }
    },
    "product_links": [
        {
            "sku": "Luma-Group",
            "link_type": "associated",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB04",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 0,
            "extension_attributes": {
                "qty": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "sku": "Luma-Group",
            "link_type": "associated",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB03",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 1,
            "extension_attributes": {
                "qty": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "sku": "Luma-Group",
            "link_type": "associated",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB05",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 2,
            "extension_attributes": {
                "qty": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "description",
            "value": "This is Group description for product."
        }
    ]
  }
}
```